# how to show list of oracle database links in datagrip?

Tags: datagrip

preview [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xg3Y.png)

I can see Tables, Views, Routines ... and I also want to see the database links of oracle connection in datagrip. How to make it visible? seems to be easy but I cannot find it

Comment: What version of DataGrip are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrip has basic support for Oracle DB links [since 2020.2 release](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2020/06/18/datagrip-2020-2-eap-2/).

[image: Basic support for Oracle DB links]